# Кодировка в php

Tags: php, веб-программирование, кодировка

Есть сайт-блог. Решил поменять язык на русский, написал код, на локалке все работает. Когда залил на хостинг, возникли проблемы с кодировкой, а именно: вместо русских символов появляются вопросительные знаки. После пары часов поиска вставил функцию `mysqli_set_charset`, но теперь новая проблема, а точнее задача. Нужно обрезать текст, если он, допустим, длиннее 100 символов. Написал код:

```
    if (strlen($row['a']) > 103) {
        $a = '';
        $j = 0;
        for(;$j<100;$j++) {
            $sym = $row['a'][$j];
            $a = $a . $sym;
        }
        $a = $a . '...';
        } else {
        $a = $row['a'];
    }
```

где `$row` - массив со строкой из базы данных. Так вот, на выходе получилась строка, куда короче, чем 100 символов. Попробовал сделать `echo $a[0];`. Вывело спец. символ из юникода типа '�'. Проверил еще некоторые индексы - тоже выходит этот знак. Помогите решить проблему: либо сделать, чтобы эти знаки вообще не появлялись, либо убрать их.

Comment: Из Азбуки:  Функция strlen() возвратит количество байт, а не число символов в строке. Длина string не обязательно будет соответствовать количеству байт в ней, так как в различных кодировках различные символы кодируются различным количеством байт, например, юникод может быть и двух-, и четырёхбайтным. Пробуй iconv_strlen. В отличие от strlen(), iconv_strlen() учитывает кодировку строки. Вот: iconv_strlen($str,'UTF-8')

Comment: @СергейВ. Да попробовал, показало такое же кол-во символов как и в БД. Тогда в чем может заключаться проблема?

Comment: Ну обрезай тогда готовой функцией, mb_substr(), что за велосипед нагородил...? Полное решение см. в ответе.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Все файлы php должны быть в кодировке utf-8 без BOM.
- При подключении к БД выставлять соединение на utf-8, вот пример для
  PDO:      `$this->conn->exec("set names utf8");`
- древний вариант:    `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");`
- Обрезать вот так mb_substr().
- Вывод на фронт с указанием `<meta charset="UTF-8">`
- **Все должно получиться.**

Comment: Спасибо! не знал про функцию mb_substr она и спасла!

Comment: Типичный набор суеверий, которые не имеют смысла сами по себе, да у тому же ещё и не имеют отношения к вопросу. Лучше оставить только один пункт, который по делу. А ещё лучше - закрыть вопрос как дубликат

Comment: @Ипатьев ну так подавайте на дубликат! Ответ выбран решением: плюс15, кто-то (НЕ ОПЯТЬ,А СНОВА) минусанул: минус2, итого ПЛЮС13. Я проповедую классическую математику, поэтому ПЛЮС13 - это неплохо. Для меня пока что лучше - оставить как есть.